# Get the number of method calls between java files

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde, eclipse-jdt

I'm writing an eclipse plug-in that needs to work on a java project to analyze inter-java-files method dependencies. I need to list the calls that one java file makes to all methods in all other java files (if any) ... Programmatically.

I thought of using Reflections, but then I will have to write my own parser to list the method calls. I'm sure eclipse has something I can use in order to achieve this, I just don't know what exactly to look for and I soon got lost in the weeds!

Any help please? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the JDT (java development toolkit) projects.  Start with the IJavaProject and collaborating classes.  You'll basically use these classes to get java-related information about the class path, implementations and references of java elements in a java project.

Comment: And in this case, get familiar with the SearchEngine class and its uses.